# Test impact analysis in tfs 2012

Tags: testing, tfs

I have setup a tfs 2012 server with the build controller and the build agent. I have a simple visual studio 2012 solution with a windows console application project and a test project on a client machine. Test impact analysis is enabled in the build definition.

Simply put, the impacted tests list that should appear on each build performed on the tfs server is never populated. I have tried to change the test runner from vs runner to mstest to no avail.

Please advise. Thanks.

EDIT: I installed VS 2012 on the server. This enabled code coverage, but still no impact analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I fixed the 'problem'.

For TIA to work, you need to successfully complete a test case in test manager, passing all test steps. Only then does the analysis file get generated. Also, I had problems with the video recording module of the test controller, which apparently also prevents the file from being generated sometimes, though this could just be a coincidence.

After successfully generating the file, subsequent builds will now have a baseline to compare against.

Have fun.