# Rejected by Server TFS Error

Tags: tfs

I am building an application but getting an error. Can someone help me to understand how to resolve this?

> Exception Message: The request was rejected by the server.Technical
>   information:  HTTP code 400: Bad Request (type
>   TeamFoundationServerInvalidRequestException)Exception Stack Trace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse
>   webResponse, WebException webException)   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.IsAuthenticationChallenge(TfsMessage
>   requestMessage, HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException
>   webException, TfsMessage& responseMessage)   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRetryChannel.Request(TfsMessage
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation
>   operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.TestImpactServer.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.ITestImpactServer.PublishBuildChanges(Uri
>   buildUri, CodeChange[] changes)   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.BuildIntegration.BuildActivities.GetImpactedTests.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)   at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location
>   resultLocation)Inner Exception Details:Exception Message: The remote
>   server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (type
>   WebException)Status: ProtocolErrorResponse Status Code:
>   BadRequestResponse Status Message: Bad RequestException Stack Trace:
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: Does this help? [Test impact analysis in tfs 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176354/test-impact-analysis-in-tfs-2012)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've just ran into the same issue with TFS2013 and our CI builds.

It seems that the error happens with the Test Impact analyser fails somehow.

You can alter your build configuration to not analyse the test impact.

It depends on which build template you are using, but for Scrum 2013, you'll find it under
It's under: Process > Test > Advanced > `Analyze Test Impact` - set this to `false`.

Comment: Timely, thank you.  +1  It'd be nice to know why this is randomly bombing out for us -- just hit the same thing myself.

Comment: I have the same issue.  This answer just tells you how to turn off Test Impact analysis, rather than why there is an error in the first place.

Comment: This is only a workaround, not a real solution... :(

Comment: For me it worked to turn it off, run the build and then turn it on again.

Comment: Yes, @Yodiz, this worked for me, as well! I'd still really like to know what put it in that state to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Jaans' "solution" works for me too, obviously. As for the cause I started seeing this error after enabling obfuscation as part of my TFS build.

Doesn't look like it's possible to disable test impact analysis only for the release configuration - debug is not obfuscated. If I really want the test impact analysis I'll need 2 build definitions and don't build the release configuration for the one where the test impact analysis is enabled.

It's also "interesting" that it breaks the build even if there are no UT.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find why it occurs, but I resolved the error using a loop and a try-catch until get impacted tests succeeded.